# How can access nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to access messages from in Nodejs (discord.js)

```
{
    "627832600865800222": {                 //guild id
        "348832732647784460": {             // author id
            "message": "hii hello"
        }
    }
}
```

```
let author_id = message.author.id
let guild_id = message.guild.id
let out = msg [guild_id].author_id.message 
        console.log(out)
```

expected output : hii hello

but resultant output : undefined 
after guild_id the output is undefined

Comment: Try `msg[guild_id][author_id].message `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change `let out = msg [guild_id].author_id.message`

to `let out = msg[guild_id][author_id].message`

MDN documentation reference for property accessors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors